# Can I find Gigantamax Pokémon outside of Max Raid Battles?

Tags: pokemon-sword-shield

I know that only certain species of Pokémon can Gigantamax, and that among those species only certain individuals can.

As far as I've seen online, Pokémon capable of Gigantamaxing can only be obtained in Max Raid Battles or through events (like the Mystery Gift Meowth).

**Is this correct? Is it impossible for a Pokémon caught in the wild outside of Max Raid Battles to be capable of Gigantamaxing?**

Answer (score 7, accepted):

TLDR: The Pokemon you find in the wild do not get the Gigantimax form and move that they would get if you caught them in a Max Raid Battle.

Although I'm sure you have already found this, here is a list of all Pokemon that have a  unique Gigantimax form/move: https://www.ign.com/wikis/pokemon-sword-shield/List_of_Every_Gigantamax_Pokemon#Gigantamax_Drednaw

I can confirm that Pokemon caught in the wild cannot get the unique Gigantimax move since when I Dynamax my Corviknight that I raised from a Rookidee, it does not get the unique form/move just the default flying Dynamax move.

<s>The real issue with this is the terminology Gigantimax.  All Pokemon can become giant and get moves based on the types of their existing moves but not all Pokemon get the unique Gigantimax form or move even if it is the same species as the ones that have the unique form/move.  I find it strange that they use the same terminology</s> but that may be a misunderstanding on my part.

Comment: "_I find it strange that they use the same terminology but that may be a misunderstanding on my part._" I believe it's the latter.  The large regular pokemon are only called Dynamax IIRC; while Gigantimax is a more specific type that also changes the appearance along with size.

Comment: It IS a misunderstanding on your part, actually. There's Dynamax, which all Pokémon can use, makes them giant and lets them use Max Moves; and there's Gigantamax, which only certain especies (and invididuals) can use, gives them a different appearance and lets them use a G-Max Move specific to each species. Also: I know not every Pokémon can Gigantamax (like your Corviknight), but I'm not certain that absolutely every Pokémon outside of Max Raid Battles is unable to. Then again, that probably cannot be confirmed 100% without checking the game's code...

Comment: Alright I'm sorry about the misunderstanding with that aspect of the game I just click through the tutorials since nothing drastic changes between the games.  In terms of your uncertainty, I'd be pretty confident in saying as of right now the Gigantimax forms are exclusive to Max Raids otherwise they would not make such a big deal in the Nintendo switch news app about which Gigantimax Pokemon are appearing in each version of the game.  It is just conjecture on my part but it would also seem logical to attract players to that unique feature in the game.

Comment: Completing your post, some events pokemon have Gigantamax (Kanto Meowth for example) and some gift pokemon do too (hi Charmander !)

Answer (score 1):

Not only can Gigantamax-capable Pokémon only be found in Max Raids (excluding events/gifts), but they can only be obtained from Max Raids where they are encountered in their Gigantamax form - a Corviknight caught from a Max Raid in its normal Dynamax form will never be capable of Gigantamaxing.

Serebii has a [list of which Max Raid dens each Pokémon can spawn in](https://www.serebii.net/swordshield/maxraidbattles.shtml). Using the Corviknight example again, you can see that it spawns in [den 32](https://www.serebii.net/swordshield/maxraidbattles/den32.shtml), [den 61](https://www.serebii.net/swordshield/maxraidbattles/den61.shtml), and [den 89](https://www.serebii.net/swordshield/maxraidbattles/den89.shtml), but only the ones encountered in den 89 will be in their Gigantamax form, and only those will be capable of Gigantamaxing after you catch them.